# linkbindingEnabled in 1.3.1 does not work the same as 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm using Backbone and jqm. I recently upgraded jqm from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2. I'm using jquery 2.0.3.

I enable and disable linkbindingEnabled based on the backbone view which is loaded. If the view has

In 1.3.1 when I click the listview it works well. The list is shown and I can select an option.

But in 1.3.2, when I click the listview, the listview shows all the options and then an exception is thrown in jquery Sizzle.error which says "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #".

The code below is the HTML code for creating a list in jqm.

```
   <div data-role="content">
       <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
                  <li data-role="list-divider">
                      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                                 <label for="select-status">Status</label>
                                 <select name="select-status" id="select-status" data-prevent-focus-zoom="true" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="d" data-iconshadow="false"
                                     data-native-menu="false" multiple>
                                     <option value="all">All</option>
                                     <option value="open">Open</option>
                                     <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                                     <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                                 </select>

                                 <select name="select-dates" id="select-dates" data-prevent-focus-zoom="true" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="d" data-native-menu="false" data-iconshadow="false">
                                     <optgroup label="Day">
                                                <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
                                                <option value="Today">Today</option>
                                                <option value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
                                                <option value="All">All days</option>
                                     </optgroup>
                                     <optgroup label="Week">
                                                <option value="ThisWeek">This Week</option>
                                                <option value="LastWeek">Last Week</option>
                                                <option value="NextWeek">Next Week</option>
                                     </optgroup>
                                 </select>
                      </fieldset>
                      <span style="display: none; padding-left: 5px;">
                                 <a id="a15" href="#" data-rel="popup">
                                     <img id="imgFilter" src="~/Content/images/filter.png" alt="filter" />
                                 </a>
                                 <span id="spanFilterText">All Appointments</span>
                      </span>
                  </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

In my backbone router I have a view which is loaded like this

```
   var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

       home: function () {
                  this.models.AppointmentList = new AppointmentList();
                  var view = new HomePageView({ model: this.models.AppointmentList });
                  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
       },

       agenda: function () {
                  if (!this.models.AppointmentList)
                      this.models.AppointmentList = new AppointmentList();
                  var view = new AgendaPageView({ model: this.models.AppointmentList })
                  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = true;
       },

   });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any news here? very interested. I get the same error when opening a popup widget, using jQM + backbone + require.

Comment: I reverted back to 1.3.1